# Endpoints for different Soap versions

Tags: xml, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have two endpoints for different clients.

I used

```
<bean id="messageFactory2" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
        <description>A message factory to support SOAP 1.2</description>
        <property name="soapVersion">
            <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

to support Soap 1.2 calls, but now the one for Soap 1.1 is not working anymore:

> Blockquote com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPVersionMismatchException: Cannot create message: incorrect content-type for SOAP version. Got: text/xml; charset=UTF-8 Expected: application/soap+xml

How can I do to manage them both?
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved using this info https://panbhatt.blogspot.ro/2011/04/spring-web-service-part-iii-creating.html